# Breaking out of user inputs in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble breaking out of my expanded list using a user input. I think I am missing how to use an `if` statement to query a list for a specific item. I need the list to break out asking for inputs when the user enters -999. I also need to exclude -999 from the list. Can you help me?

The `print(scoreLst)` is just so can test and see how it is working as I use it.

```
scoreLst =[]
score = ()
lst1 = True

print("The list ends when user inputs -999")
scoreLst.append(input("Enter the test score: "))
while lst1 == True:
    score1 = scoreLst.append(input("Enter another test score: "))
    print(scoreLst)     
    if score1 != -999:
        lst1 ==  True
    else:
        scoreLst.remove(-999)
        lst1 == False
```

Comment: Append after validation not before into the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes:

- convert test scores to `int`
- `list.append` returns `None`, don't assign it to anything; use `scoreLst[-1]` instead of `score1`
- don't use `list.remove` to delete the last element of the list, `list.pop()` will work nicely
- `lst1 == False` is comparison, `lst1 = False` is assignment
- you'd create an infinite loop and `break` once the user enters -999, I see no need for `lst1`

End result:

```
scoreLst = []

print("The list ends when user inputs -999")
scoreLst.append(int(input("Enter the test score: ")))

while True:
    scoreLst.append(int(input("Enter another test score: ")))
    if scoreLst[-1] == -999:
        scoreLst.pop()
        break
```

Comment: This works great and is simpler. out of curiosity do i have to assign list.pop life below?
        scoreLst.pop(-999)
        break

Comment: @AndrewBodin `list.pop()`  removes the last element of the list and the last element is -999 (we specifically check this in `scoreLst[-1] == -999`), so no, you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Btw, if you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: I also appreciate the explanation to why things work the way they do. Its been accepted.